# Authenticate REST request to Google APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a problem authenticating a REST request to Google APIs. Usually, Google have client packages that do it for you.

Now, I am using Document Translation service, which is still in preview, so I can not use the package. Docs are really confusing when it comes to authenticating a REST request. When I am using a package, I am giving it a JSON credentials file with this template:

```
{
  "type": "xxx",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "xxx",
  "client_email": "xxx",
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "auth_uri": "xxx",
  "token_uri": "xxx",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xxx",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx"
}
```

Can I send a REST request and just use some of this data to authenticate, just like when I use the client packages? I saw in a few places that I should generate a token with this data and use a token to authenticate. Do I need to generate and use a token? If yes, how to create a token in NodeJS?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hey Tanaike. First, thank you for your time answering my question. Yes, you understand my question correctly. Primary, I wanted to find a way to authenticate without creating a token in the first place. That flow does not make sense to me. We are authenticating ourselves when obtaining a token, so why can't we just send a request directly with the same data that we used when obtaining a token. I see that you are Google expert, so maybe you can explain to me why this flow is necessary? Thanks!

Comment: Also, to answer your question about my current situation. As I said in question, I am using Document Translation service, which is still in preview. Because of that, it is still not documented in the relevant package documentation. After checking all relevant Docs, I opened package's source code and start investigating. I found that in `v3beta1` folder there are functions that support document translation, even if there is no documentation about them. So, I just used those functions, and I implemented authentication through the package.

Comment: I also noticed one more interesting problem. I opened separate question about it, so If you have time maybe you can check that one also? I didn't found the solution about it yet. Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67645265/14389830

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question of requirement of the access token, I think that this is for the security. For example, an API key can be used with Google APIs. But in this case, API key can be used for only the public content with GET method. API key cannot be used for non public content and the method except for GET method like POST, PUT and so on. For retrieving the access token, there are 2 patterns.

Comment: Those are OAuth2 and the service account. At OAuth2, it is required to authorize the scopes by using own browser. I think that because the API directly access to the user's content. At service account, it is not required to use the browser, and the access token can be retrieved using a script. I think that because in the case of service account, the content is different from the user's account. By these, I think that the access token is required to be used for the Google APIs. If I misunderstood your new question and this was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- You have the credential file of the service account.
- You want to use the Google APIs using the service account.
- You want to achieve this using Node.js. But, you don't want to use [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client). You want to use this service account without googleapis for Node.js.
- Your question has following 2 questions.

  1. Can I send a REST request and just use some of this data to authenticate, just like when I use the client packages?
  2. Do I need to generate and use a token? If yes, how to create a token in NodeJS?

### Answer for question 1:

I think that it's yes.

### Answer for question 2:

I think that it's yes. In order to use Google APIs using the service account, it is required to retrieve the access token using the service account. The sample script for retrieving the access token from the service account without googleapis for Node.js is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this case, 2 libraries of `crypto` and `request` are used. And, please set `privateKey` and `clientEmail`. This script is from [this post](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/04/02/retrieving-access-token-using-service-account-for-node.js-without-using-googleapis/).

```
const cryptor = require('crypto');
const request = require('request');

const privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n###-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // private_key of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
const clientEmail = "###"; // client_email of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account

const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]; // Sample scope

const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
const header = {
  alg: "RS256",
  typ: "JWT",
};
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
const claim = {
  iss: clientEmail,
  scope: scopes.join(" "),
  aud: url,
  exp: (now + 3600).toString(),
  iat: now.toString(),
};

const signature = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64') + "." + Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(claim)).toString('base64');

var sign = cryptor.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update(signature);
const jwt = signature + "." + sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

request({
  method: "post",
  url: url,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    assertion: jwt,
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  }),
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(body);
});
```

- In this sample, as a sample scope, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is used. About this, please modify the scopes for your actual situation.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following value is returned. You can use the access token from this value and can use the Google APIs using this access token.

```
{
  "access_token":"###",
  "expires_in":3599,
  "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

### Note:

- As an important point, for example, when you use the Google Drive API using this script, the Drive of service account is different from your Google Drive. Please be careful this. When you want to use the file on your Drive using the service account, it is required to share the file with the email of service account.

### References:

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)
- [Retrieving Access Token using Service Account for Node.js without using googleapis](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/04/02/retrieving-access-token-using-service-account-for-node.js-without-using-googleapis/)