# Remove "Machine Translated by Google"

Tags: google-api, translation, google-translation-api

I am using a new Google's Document Translation API that is still in preview. After it translate the document, translated document have `Machine Translated by Google` text at the top of each page. How can I disable adding that text?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do natively via Google Cloud, according to Google Technical Support. While you could theoretically do post-processing, you might run afoul of the requirements listed in [Google's Attribution Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution) .  For example:

> Whenever you display translation results from Google Translate directly to users, you must make it clear to users that they are viewing automatic translations from Google Translate using the appropriate text or brand elements.